# Updated Orientdb to 2.1.5 and now Studio is missing

Tags: orientdb

Does anyone have some tips where to look, as to why Studio might not work? I can access the database via the console, but when I try to access Studio, I get a redirect and then a 404. So my server is up, but Studio seems broken.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Scott

Comment: scott did you downloaded from the website?

Studio should be in plugins directory of you installation. Can you check?

Comment: Hi Scott, I downloaded it from the official download page and it seems to work fine. How did you update? I suggest you to download a fresh install and just copy your databases folder

Comment: Thanks you two. I now have it working, but by downloading the Enterprise edition and upgrading to it. And, since it is a dev box, I'll stick with that for a while, until the next version. When 2.1.6 is out, then I'll play with upgrading again and see if the problem happens. I think it might have just been a fluke or something stupid I did.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, then I found that Studio is delivered as zip file (in `%ORIENTDB_HOME%/plugins/studio-2.1.zip`) and there is no `studio` directory in `%ORIENTDB_HOME%/www` (where default index redirects when accessing [Studio](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb-studio.wiki/Home-page.html)). I've unpacked `www` directory from `studio-2.1.zip` into `%ORIENTDB_HOME%/www`, renamed it to `studio` and now it's working.

I have OrientDB installed as Windows service (service is starting automatically and was running when I tried to access Studio).

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure what happened, but I since then installed OrientDB several times and Studio worked in all the installations.